# Trouble with mysql join and where AND

Tags: mysql

I want to join two tables and select the data and insert in third table, but it's not working.
The code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO attendance(cid, sid) SELECT course.cid, student.id FROM course
        INNER JOIN student ON student.id=course.cid
        WHERE course.cid=$course_id AND student.id=$student_id";
```

when I remove the WHERE clause it works.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Is that PHP, you are writing code in?

Comment: Are the course and student ID numeric values or do they contain any other symbols? If yes, you need to wrap them in quotes.

Comment: It does not produce any errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate your variables properly. Try this (Assuming that you are using PHP),

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO attendance(cid, sid) SELECT course.cid, student.id FROM course
        INNER JOIN student ON student.id=course.cid
        WHERE course.cid=". $course_id ." AND student.id=". $student_id .";";
```

**Note**: You should use extra single quotes if `cid` and `student.id` are strings. But as they are Ids, I am assuming that they are numeric.

Hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot every body

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have contradicting join and where conditions.
You are joining on `student.id=course.cid` and then again in the where conditions you are checking the same fields. Verify the join conditions and where clause are as intended or not.

Comment: Yes!! I was thinking same too.